# Change the background and font color of TimePicker widget

Tags: java, android

I wanna change the background color and font color of TimePicker widget. I have found that background depends on colorAccent , but is it possible to change the background without changing colorAccent. Also I wanna change color of Hour Numbers and Minute Numbers.

Comment: Have you already checked out `Drawable`s? In regards to font colors, you should ask separate question (although solution might be the same, I wouldn't know).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Can you explain me further about Drawable? How can I access Drawable of widget and how can I edit it.

Comment: <sarcasm>Major android expert here</sarcasm>. Each android `View` has a property [android:background](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background) (it can be accessed programmatically using `setBackground`, or via view xml config), which is a reverence to some [Drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html). There is a [ColorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) that can be used to just set a flat color of the view.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov (didn't know that those properties are called drawable) I have tried , but it doesn't change the background of widget's header. The color for header is determined by colorAccent

Comment: Header's not affected probably because header is not a background - it's something else, which makes sense. Try `android:foreground`, maybe, or find the header child element inside the picker, and set background on that.